# How can i change the selected item in bottom Navigation View while going to the back fragment?

Tags: android

I want to change the selected item id when I press back key and the fragment move to the previous fragment.

```
BottomNavigationView navigationView;
navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(navigationView);


 navigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.mHome:
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = 
getSupportFragmentManager();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction 
fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame,new 
HomeFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                break;
```

Comment: Just check that item in onResume() of the fragment.

Comment: Read [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html). You just need to communicate b/w two fragment.

Comment: That isnt work for me in onResume(), that throws nullPointerException on Starting the fragment. @R.R.M

Comment: I have posted an answer. Please refer that.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line in onResume() of your fragment:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.this_fragment_menu_id);
```

Where MainActivity is the class where you loaded navigation view.

Comment: Not working for mr buddy , Fragment cant even get loaded , just blank screen showed up.

Answer (score 0):

Override `OnBckPressed()` and implemet `FragmentTransaction` inside it.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame,new  HomeFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

Comment: not worked for me Buddy, After adding that code, i cant even back track to previous fragment..!